# Svg paths doesn't look very sharp

Tags: svg

Look at the following svg image:

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking this, but the lines don't look super sharp to me. Especially if the image is smaller.

Is there anyway to make the lines look sharper than this? I would think that because it is a vector image, it must be able to look sharper.

Here is a screenshot how it looks to me if the image is smaller:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line pixelation comes from the fact that video card is a raster-graphics device (not vector-graphics). The same goes for monitor. So vector image must be converted to pixels and feed into video device frame buffer. Thus pixelation occurs no matter what. Anti-aliasing helps to blur line edges. But you already enabled anti-aliasing with `shape-rendering: geometricprecision;` 
There are more edge pixel averaging techniques, but all of them (especially newest ones) works with raster data. About these - consult game graphics developers for info.

**UPDATE**
*(About your note that on smaller images quality drops more.)*

Half-rhetorical question: Have you ever tried to resize Mona Lisa picture into 1 pixel ? At this 
zoom-out level all pictures looks similar. Reasoning behind this is that the more we squeeze the picture - the less pixels are for us to operate, so we loose more details. You can't keep same quality with smaller amount of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If I take a look at your .svg with Inkscape, I'm able to zoom in and out without any loss. At the zoom of 2260% the upper 'dot' of the three looks very curvy. The very left end at the plus sign has a approx. 1 px wide line down.

As far as I understand this field, you should search for a typographer (or somebody who knows fonts better) and not for a vector graphics expert. The only tag 'svg' could be misleading here.